# I would like to find a new use for my left over sm pet bedding (unused of course. )

Tags: potting-soil

Care fresh sm pet bedding , I bought this over the summer because we found a baby bunny all alone in the street and I brought it home took care of it till It got strong enough to be released back out into the wild but I was using this temporarily to put in its little habitat. Now that I have a good amount left over along with hay and some dry flour mixtures for rabbits I was thinking of a good way to repurpose these things. I don't know if it's safe to put it into my indoor potting soil or not I'm looking online I'm getting mixed results if it's not going to serve a purpose being in the soil then I'm not going to add it and I don't want to harm any plants so I wanted to see if anyone else had anything to say about it. If you could let me know if it's good to put into healthy soil to help with drainage or anything I'd like to know that along with the leftover hay and the leftover dried flowers I have thank you.

Comment: Hi Kathleen, what is the bedding made of?  Wood shavings?  Recycled paper? A picture of it would help

Comment: Do you have any outside plants? Most bedding materials make a good mulch, not so much a soil amendment directly.

Comment: The package hides its content as **comfyfluff** and biodegradable, suggesting it may be compostable. Well, now we know nothing. It looks like newspaper granola, not hay.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought on repurposing the supplies is to find another bunny caretaker who could use them.  Maybe they can give you some bunny waste in return, which does not need to be composted and can be added directly to your soil.

My second thought is that, depending on what the bedding is, I would probably not want to use it directly as a soil amendment.  Do you compost?  The bedding would make great compost.  Soiled bedding would be even better, if you still had any.  This could help if any urine or anything else is too 'strong' and let what I assume is high-carbon bedding soak up the nutrients it needs from the compost pile instead of your plant's soil.

My third thought is that, maybe composting doesn't matter that much for clean bedding and hay.  It sounds like the bedding you have would compost 'in ground' just fine.  I think most beddings and hay can make a good mulch for top dressing too.

Personally I would probably mix them directly into my potting soil and mulch with it if I didn't have a compost pile already.  But you sound like a more conscientious gardener than I am, and composting the material first would be safer.